# LocalDateTime Serialization in Spring Boot 1.4 Release returns array

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, iso8601

Recently I updated my project to use Spring Boot 1.4-Release, however, the serialization of `LocalDateTime` seems to be broken.
With below **`pom.xml`**

```
...

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

....
```

and **Jackson** configuration in `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

`LocalDateTime` object is formatted as an array, something like **`[2016, 8, 17, 11, 50, 0]`**, as opposed to **`"2016-08-17T11:50:00"`** which was what I got when using Spring Boot 1.4.RC1

However, `LocalDate` can still be correctly interpreted to **`"2016-08-17"`**.

Can anyone help? Much appreciated!!

Comment: If you haven't changed anything from RC1 to release then this is most likely a bug and should be added as an issue on GitHub. If you have a sample project that exhibits the issue that would help a lot to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. I'm using 1.4.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all! It's actually my bad ... in order to reduce the network traffic time, the result is serialized and then compressed before transmission, however, I forgot to set the WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMES‌​TAMPS feature to false in the manually created ObjectMapper